# Print After match

Tags: file, unix, grep

I want to print data after match.
My file format like:

```
SSID:WIFI-1
Passphrase:1234ABCD
SSID:WIFI-2
Passphrase:123456789
SSID:WIFI-3
Passphrase:1234ABCD
```

If word after SSID match I have to do some operation.

After matching `SSID` I've to connect to that WiFi output: out of this going to use for connecting WiFi.

I've tried `sed`, and a grep command like

```
grep -oP '(?<=/SSID/)\w+' list_wifi.txt
sed 's:.*SSID::' list_wifi.txt
```

I tried this also but this print all the data after occurrence, but I want to print WIFI-1,WIFI-2 like only.

Comment: What operation? What is your output needed? What attempts have you made?

Comment: Operation: after matching SSID I,ve to connect to that wifi                                               Output: out of this going to use for connecting wifi                                                              I've tried sed, grep command grep -oP '(?<=/SSID/)\w+' list_wifi.txt , sed 's:.*SSID::' list_wifi.txt  I tried this also but this print all the data after occurance, but I want to print WIFI-1,WIFI-2 like only

Comment: Try `grep -oP '^SSID:\K.+' file`

Comment: this helps.. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Note that `(?<=/SSID/)\w+` does not work due to `/` around `SSID`, lack of `:` after `SSID` and the `\w` pattern does not match hyphens. `sed` won't work like this because it will keep the non-matching lines in the output, unless you use specific options. Also, you used `:` as a delimiter for the `s` command, so you need to escape the literal `:` in the pattern. Or, just use another delimiter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `grep` with `-P` option, you are using GNU `grep` and the following solution will do the job:

```
grep -oP '^SSID:\K.+' file
```

The pattern matches

- `^` - start of the line
- `SSID:` - a `SSID:` substring
- `\K` - a match reset operator that discards all text matched so far in the mathc memory buffer
- `.+` - any 1 or more chars to the rest of the line.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/TJ2RN7/1).